# NotWritablePropertyException when deploying the application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im getting the below exception when i deploy the application, Does anyone know the work around?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateUtil' defined in class path resource [spring-hibernate-cfg.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [com.library.database.HibernateUtil]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
```

Answer (score 1):

add `setSessionFactory();` method to `com.go.database.HibernateUtil`,

you have defined property `sessionFactory` and injected into `HibernateUtil`, Spring will use setter injection and you don't have setter method for this property so it is failing